# Confused with caching setup

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm maintaining a private large monorepository that is build with pnpm workspaces.

I'm trying to add NX but I have very unreliable compilation. I suspect I misconfigured NX because `pnpm nx reset` often solve my issues.

The documentation is confusing for me, I'm not sure how to tell Nx which folders are the actual output.

Here's what I have :

### repo layout:

- `(root)`

  - `apps/*` : contains multiple apps (leaves of my dep tree)
  - `packages/*` : common libraries, shared across apps or other libs
  - `tools/*` : custom compiler, eslint rules, ...

All my packages (app, package, or tool) are built using Typscript (+ webpack for some), and share a common layout :

- `./src` : my actual source files
- `./lib`: output of the TS compiler
- `./dist` : output of the webpack step, for apps that should be deployable

These paths are relative to each package root.

Because this layout is shared, I setup root `nx.json` this way:

```
{
    "extends": "nx/presets/npm.json",
    "tasksRunnerOptions": {
        "default": {
            "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
            "options": {
                "cacheableOperations": ["build", "test", "release", "build:prod", "pretty"],
                "parallel": true,
                "maxParallel" : 8
            }
        }
    },
    "targetDefaults": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"],
            "outputs" : ["{projectRoot}/dist", "{projectRoot}/lib"]
        },
        "serve": {
            "dependsOn": ["build"]
        }
    },
    "affected": {
        "defaultBase": "develop"
    }
}
```

However, even with this setup I still have to nx reset to have a proper build.

What did I make wrong?

Is there some kinda verbose flag that may understand what and when is cached ?

**[Edit 09-02-2022]** Add some precision after upgrade NX to 14.6.3

If I left the `outputs` definition as is, I got this error when trying to compile "app1":

> `NX   ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\path\to\myrepo\apps\app1\tools\compiler\lib'`

This folder obviously does not exists. I may be either `'D:\path\to\myrepo\apps\tools\compiler\lib'` or `D:\path\to\myrepo\apps\app1\node_modules\@myrepo\compiler\lib` (assuming tool1 package is name @myrepo/compiler in its package.json

If I remove the outputs directive, NX daemon does not seems to properly detect the changes and I have to manually reset the NX cache (no cloud cache) to have fresh compiled lib

However, running from the root of the workspace this command works:

```
pnpm nx run @myrepo/app1:build
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? I may be in the same boat.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarifiy behavior